# C# basic school project SOS

Tags: c#

I am new to programming and I would be delighted if someone could help me with the following question: "Write a program that ask for the class and number of students. after asking for the name of student, ask for the grades by the Name of student, show average and show highest grade". I am stuck at part 3, and can't the link the names to next part. This is what I got so far:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        // 1 give a name and number of students
        Console.Write("Class = ");
        Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Number of students = ");
        int aantalStudenten = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine();

        // 2 ask for the names
        int[] aantal = new int[aantalStudenten];
        Random RandomNumber = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < aantalStudenten; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("Geef naam van de {0}e student : ", i + 1);
            string studentNaam  = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        Console.WriteLine();

        // 3 give the grade of each student by the name                      
        for (int j = 0; j < aantalStudenten; j++)                
        {
            Console.Write("Cijfer van {0} : "); // here i need the students name)//
            int cijfers = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        //class avarege here


        //highest grade of the class
        int hoogste = stuCijfer.Max();
        Console.WriteLine("De hoogste cijfer is {}," hoogste;

        //name and grade of each student
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: store the names in a string array and then use that as a parallel array with the grade. SO they will both use the same index of j when recalling the name. so name 0 will map to grade 0 ect. With the grades stored as ints or floats you can compare them with each other to find the max grade. as you loop to do this you can store the index into a variable which will be used once the loop is closed to display the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Console.Write("Class = ");
        Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Number of students = ");
        int aantalStudenten = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine();

        // 2 ask for the names
        string[] namen = new string[aantalStudenten];
        int[] cijfers = new int[aantalStudenten];
        Random RandomNumber = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < aantalStudenten; i++){
            Console.Write("Geef naam van de {0}e student : ", i + 1);
             namen[i] = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        Console.WriteLine();

        // 3 give the grade of each student by the name                      
        for (int i = 0; i < aantalStudenten; i++){
            Console.Write("Cijfer van {0} : ", namen[i]);     // here i need the students name)//
            cijfers[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        double gemiddeld = 0;
        //class avarege here
        for (int i = 0; i < cijfers.Count(); i++) {
            gemiddeld += cijfers[i];
        }

        gemiddeld = gemiddeld / cijfers.Count();
        Console.WriteLine("Het gemiddelde van de klas is: {0}", gemiddeld);


        //highest grade of the class
        int hoogste = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < cijfers.Count(); i++) {
            if (cijfers[i] > hoogste) {
                hoogste = cijfers[i];
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("De hoogste cijfer is {0}",hoogste);

        //name and grade of each student
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop");
        Console.ReadKey();
```

You should put the names of the students in a list the way you are working now you are overwriting each time the user enters a new name. and then u can loop over the names storing the score in an array in this case u can use two separate one's but it would be better to use a dictionary or a 2D array. 
but good luck further

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your trying to get a string where you're picking out the name but it might have been converted to an int. Change the part where you converted it to a int when you received the name. 
It also looks like you have for int j. Before you named it int i. Make sure it references back to the exact same name for what you identified each time.

on a side note you could try to store the names into an array and pull them out be referencing the array. That might help.

Answer (score 0):

If I were to code such a program properly I would create a new `Student` class to contain a name and a score, then create a list or array to contain multiple instances of `Student`. Hopefully you're familiar with the concepts of creating new classes, and with lists or arrays. If you need help understanding any of those, let me know.

Comment: At this level it would be easier to use parallel arrays and multidimensional arrays.

Comment: @Shon If one is not familiar with the concept of classes and encapsulation, then parallel arrays or multidimensional arrays might be appropriate, but this exercise seems *designed* to teach one about the use for classes, and if one is familiar with these concepts, I would assert that it's actually the simpler solution.

Comment: Class here refers to classroom and not the programming term

Comment: @Shon I'm aware of that, which is why I said "hopefully you're familiar with the concepts of creating new classes...". If the poster is not familiar, then this may not be the right answer for them, but if they want to learn, I'm prepared to answer more questions on the topic. The reason I think the question is designed for understanding the need for classes is because a Student is an entity with multiple properties in this case.